# Movie where the protagonist tried to use a glove to evade fingerprint sensor but told the security camera is in color

Tags: story-identification, movie

The protagonist is either taking something or purchasing it, to evade detection he uses a glove, hoping to hide his fingerprint. He then asks the officer/cashier if the security camera is in color, and getting the "well of course" reply, implying his attempt failed. Indeed, his enemy later noticed the oddity of wearing gloves while reviewing the record.

My memory is hazy, but either before/after that scene, he was going somewhere, his car's GPS suggests a different route saying it's faster or the usual route is blocked, but instead he ends up in a place where he's beaten.

Watched the movie on TV before 2002, the overall atmosphere is dystopian-future.